# Remove everything but numbers and decimals from string

Tags: python, regex

I'm scraping prices and I want to ensure the price string doesn't contain anything such as:

- Whitespaces
- Letters
- More than one decimal
- Special characters such as commas

Right now I'm starting to do something like:

```
def parse_price(price):
    price = price.replace(' ', '')
    price = price.replace(',', '')
    return price
```

Which I don't like the look of.

Allowed:

```
1.00
432.32
32324.03
```

Not allowed:

```
$1.00
 3.43
C$32.55
£16.43
324,4343.20
```

Comment: Have you looked into regular expressions?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if I can remove all the criteria in one regex?

Comment: Why `1.00` is allowed but not `3.43`? What about `the price is 123.45`?

Comment: @Toto Note the leading white space

Answer (score 2):

This can be pretty quickly solved with a regex expression. The easiest way would be to do:

```py
import re

txt = "$23A. 234."
r = re.compile("[^\d\$\.]")
x = r.sub('', txt)
x = re.findall("\$[\d]*\.[\d]*", x)
print(x)
```

This will remove any characters that are NOT a digit, not a period, and not a dollar sign. Then use a pattern to match dollar sign, numbers, period, dollar sign. Note: if there are any more periods after the first, it won't grab anything after. I may update to fix this, but this should be good for now.

### Edit:

To fit OP's criteria, here's a revised version for no dollar sign and two decimal places:

```
import re

txt = "$23A. 234."
r = re.compile("[^\d\.]")
x = r.sub('', txt)
x = re.findall("[\d]*\.\d\d", x)
print(x)
```

Comment: The OP said that `$` was not allowed, but good answer that is easy to adapt.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thank you for letting me know I updated it to fit.